# SharePoint 2013 - Set as startup project breaks debugging

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I create an App for SharePoint with Provider Hosting (MVC). I then immediately put a break-point on the Index of the Home controller and click play, break point gets hit all is good :)

I then right click the SharePoint app and set as start up project. Then I run again and my break-point doesn't get hit.

To get debugging back again I have to start a new debug instance of the MVC project and then start a new debug instance of my SharePoint app.

**What's going on?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work around to this problem you shouldn't set the startup project by right clicking, instead follow these steps:

1. Right click your solution -> select `Properties`
2. Select the `Multiple startup projects` option
3. Set all your projects action to `None`
4. Now go ahead and set your ASP.NET (Provider hosted web app) to `Start`
5. Next (if you have multiple SharePoint apps) select the one you are currently working on and set its action to `Start`

Now when pressing `F5` your breakpoints will be hit inside your provider hosted app.